# $\lim_{ t\rightarrow \infty} h(t)= \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, definition

If $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is a continuous function. What is 
the definition of what it means to say $\lim_{ t\rightarrow \infty} f(t)= \infty$?

Would this be the correct definition?
The function $f$ has a limit at $\infty$ if there exists a number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $M$ for which $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$ for all $x \in$  Dom$ f \cap (M, \infty)$.

Comment: When you write $h$ do you mean $f$?  Note that when you write $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that usually means that the domain of $f$ is all of $\Bbb{R}$.  Your definition of what it means for $f$ to have a limit $L$ at $\infty$ appears correct.

Comment: However, that definition is not the one you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The condition that $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$ would mean that as $\varepsilon \to 0$ then $f(x)\to L$.  Intuitively what you mean when you say $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$$ is that no matter how large a number $N$ you pick, there will always be a point $x$ after which your function $f(x)$ will be greater than $N$.  Formally we can write the following:  For all $N>0$, there exists an $x'>0$ such that for all $x>x'$ we have $f(x) > N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following definition works, and $f$ need not be continuous.

> For all $L$ there exists $M$ such that $f(x)>L$ for all $x>M$.